# Sitecore - not mapping indexed field when using ContentSearchManager from Solr Index

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore

- Sitecore 8.2.6
- Solr 6.6.2

**Problem:**

Cannot map birthday (any -- see attachment) fields to the C# model. All come up as either `null` (when using `returnType="string"`), or `01/01/0001` (when using `returnType="datetime"`)

[image]

I'm using the `sitecore_analytics_index` for obtaining search results for EXM contacts. When viewing the Solr index (via localhost:8984/solr), I can clearly see the fields.

`dateofbirth` and `contact.dateofbirth` I can see in the `Fields` collection, when viewing the an object in the list of `BirthdaySearchResultItem` return from searching the index.

I am able to map `contact.tags_sm` and `contact.contactid` correctly.

```
public class BirthdaySearchResultItem : SearchResultItem, IObjectIndexers
{
    [IndexField("contact.tags_sm")]
    public string[] ContactList { get; set; } // maps correctly

    [DataMember]
    [IndexField("contact.contactid")]
    public virtual Guid ContactId { get; set; } // maps correctly

    [DataMember]
    [IndexField("contact.dateofbirth")]
    public virtual DateTime BirthDay { get; set; } // have tried using "string"

    [DataMember]
    [IndexField("dateofbirth")]
    public virtual DateTime BirthDay1 { get; set; } // have tried using "string"

    [DataMember]
    [IndexField("contact.dateofbirth_t")]
    public virtual DateTime BirthDay2 { get; set; } // have tried using "string"

    [DataMember]
    [IndexField("contact.dateofbirth_t_en")]
    public virtual DateTime BirthDay3 { get; set; } // have tried using "string"

    [DataMember]
    [IndexField("birthday")]
    public virtual DateTime BirthDay4 { get; set; } // have tried using "string"
}
```

---

```
      <index id="sitecore_analytics_index">
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
          <fieldMap>
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="contact.contactid"                     returnType="guid"/>
              <field fieldName="contact.dateofbirth"                   returnType="datetime"/>  <!-- have tried "string" as well -->
              <field fieldName="dateofbirth"                           returnType="datetime" />
              <field fieldName="contact.dateofbirth_t"                 returnType="datetime" />
              <field fieldName="contact.dateofbirth_t_en"              returnType="datetime" />

.... omitted for brevity
```

---

```
        var indexName = "sitecore_analytics_index";
        var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);

        using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())  //IContactDetailFacet
        {
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<BirthdaySearchResultItem>();
            var test = context.GetQueryable<BirthdaySearchResultItem>().ToList();

        }
```

Comment: Did you try to check what sitecore returns in searchResultItem["contact.dateofbirth"] ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data sample I can see that you use the leading "/" instead of "-" which is important as Solr uses the ISO format for dates, see [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html#working-with-dates). Therefore, I suggest you to add the format attribute to your index definition first, for example:

```
<field fieldName="contact.dateofbirth"   returnType="datetime"   format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" />
```

And then in your model use `Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime()` method to convert an ISO formatted date string to a DateTime class.